# jquery load() crashes browser when run after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I may be totally wrong here, I am trying to load an iframe as soon as I submit a form. Here is the code

```
$("#listings-form").submit();
$("#hiddeniframe-listings-form").load(alert('done!'));
```

Doing this produces `too much recursion` and even crashes browser, chrome or mozilla.

Comment: Try commenting out the `$("#listings-form").submit();` and check if you still get the `too much recursion` error. Perhaps the submit event hander for `#listings-form` was set to call itself causing the infinite recursion. 

Also don't you need to specify a url and wrap the `alert` statement in a funtion for the `.load()` method?

Comment: @fsong, you are the man, yes the submit is crashing page but now how do I take care of this situation, I want to check the response returned in iframe, which is actually a JSON object, after the form is submitted to the hidden iframe.

Comment: Just to clear things up `$("#listings-form").submit();` makes a synchronous POST request to the server with the form data and then loads the JSON response in an iframe once the POST request is done? Did you define this function somewhere and if so could you post it?

Comment: @fsong, thanks for your tip, the issue is solved, if you post your suggestion as an answer we can close this question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out the `$("#listings-form").submit();` and check if you still get the `too much recursion error.` Perhaps the submit event hander for #listings-form was set to call itself causing the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) accepts function reference:

```
$('#hiddeniframe-listings-form').load(
    function() {
        alert('done!');
    }
);
```

Comment: I am using this http://api.jquery.com/load-event/, I am actually submitting form to a hidden iframe and the iframe then loads up with response

Comment: I have updated my answer. It requires a function reference as its argument.

Comment: I did not find the code you have given to be very different in approach from mine but I still used it & same error :(

Comment: The way you are calling `load()` is wrong. `load()` accepts a function reference (look at my code). Anyway, I was able to correct one of your code's errors.

Comment: Well, I am not a JS ninja, isn't passing a function same as function reference? The problem is not with load() its with submit

Comment: A function *name* is a reference in JavaScript. However, `alert()` is a function call and not a function reference.